# org.apache.wicket.util.resource.IResourceStream throws javascript error. Unable to download file

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, wicket, wicket-1.5

Using org.apache.wicket.util.resource.IResourceStream I created zip file at server and in outputstream written the same zip file. But it throws the following error which I'm breaking my head. Any suggestion?

```
Timestamp: 7/25/2012 3:13:28 PM
Error: not well-formed
Source File: XXX
Line: 1, Column: 3
Source Code:
PK
```

Java Code

```
        AjaxButton one = new AjaxButton("one"){     
                @Override
                public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target,Form form) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {

                        {
                        IResourceStream iResourceStream  = null;
                        iResourceStream = new AbstractResourceStreamWriter(){

                            @Override
                            public String getContentType() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return "application/zip";
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void write(OutputStream output) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                File tmpFile = null;
                                String batchFileName = "batch_"+dateFormat.format(new Date())".zip";
                                File zipFile = new File(batchFileName);
                                FileOutputStream zipFileOutputStream = null;
                                ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = null;
                                try
                                {
                                    zipFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
                                    zipOutputStream = 
                                        new ZipOutputStream(zipFileOutputStream);    
                                    zipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
                                    for(XXX)
                                    {
// create tmpFile zip file here                                 
                                                    ZipEntry zipAdd = new ZipEntry(tmpFile.getName());  
                                                    System.out
                                                            .println(tmpFile.getName());
                                                    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipAdd);
                                                    zipOutputStream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(tmpFile)));
                                                    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    if(zipOutputStream != null){
                                        try {
                                            zipOutputStream.flush();
                                            zipOutputStream.close();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {                   
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if(zipFileOutputStream != null){
                                        try {
                                            zipFileOutputStream.flush();
                                            zipFileOutputStream.close();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {                   
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    try
                                    {
                                        {
                                            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
                                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                            int len;
                                            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                                                output.write(buf, 0, len);
                                            }
                                            in.close();
                                            output.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }


                            }

                        };

                        getRequestCycle()
                        .setRequestTarget(new ResourceStreamRequestTarget(iResourceStream)
                        .setFileName("batch.zip"));


                    } else {

                    }

                } catch (Exception e)
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an AJAX request but instead of sending back XML (which the JS code in the browser expects) you're sending binary data. That's why you're getting the "not well-formed" error - it's not well-formed xml.

There are two ways to make this work. One is to simply not do an AJAX submit and use a regular   `Button` instead of an `AjaxButton`. I recommend this one.

If you need to do some other AJAX work (updating a panel or something like that) and then want to present the download, have a look at this: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/ajax-update-and-file-download-in-one-blow.html